# how to extract format of number from a string using pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a column in my table which have this value :

```
  |col_A|
  -------
  |00140|
  -------
  |00120|
  -------
  |00058|
  -------
  |00009|
  -------
  |00052|
```

I want to delete all 0 in the left. 
I use pyspark to build the dataframe.
You find as below an exemple :

```
while tab.col_A.like('0%'):
        tab = tab.withColumn('tab_B', tab['col_A'][2:5])
```

When I try to execute this code I have this error :

> Cannot convert column into bool

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this code :

```
tab = tab.withColumn("col_B", F.regexp_extract(tab['col_A'], '[1-9][0-9]*',0))
```

The problem is resolved.

Thanks,